# Customize casGenericSuccess Page

Tags: java, jsp, cas

We are using Jasig-CAS...and I'm looking to show the currently logged in users UID on the casGenericSuccess page (we are customizing it). How can this be done?

Can cas: tags be used as is?...or do I need to import a lib?

What about something simple like:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("uid") %>
```

(doesn't work)

Comment: Add `setAttribute` after successful login `session.setAttribute("uid", value);` then only you can get `session.getAttribute("uid");`

Comment: No...but is it set by CAS itself in some way? We are not modifying any underlying code for the CAS app...just the view of the casGenericSuccess page

Comment: What is CAS app?? Check your CAS has set the session attribute "uid" or not?

Comment: "CAS app" I am referring to is CAS itself...Jasig CAS http://www.jasig.org/cas We want to customize the successful login page.